# macOS alternative to Meld

Tags: mojave, homebrew

The mojave upgrade from 10.14.5 to 10.14.6 broke my old VLC install (already fixed by upgrading the VLC install) and I think it has also broken my Meld 3.19.2.osx6 build provided through Homebrew.

I don't find any build more recent than mine.

What's the different thought way to meld in macOS? (What's the alternative free (and *gratis*) program?)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this fork?  https://yousseb.github.io/meld/
Maybe that will work???

As for alternatives there is FileMerge that comes with Xcode.  To open it from the terminal, run opendiff.

Comment: The fork, I'd seen it! I think it's staying in the same level as the brew build. `opendiff` didn't helped me much (I didn't know this before you) because it's a horrible UX compared to Meld (so you don't get the accept (yet)), but you definitely get the upvote. :)

Comment: You may want to take a look at this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229142/what-are-the-alternatives-for-meld-graphical-diff-tool-on-osx. This has a whole list of different alternative.  I haven't used any but you might find what you are looking for.

Comment: I think I turned to Meld years ago because of being much more pleasant than KDiff, but's definitely worth trying KDiff back!

Comment: So KDiff just works, but is still really really rough compared to Meld. :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite happy with [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), but I haven't tested it in Mojave.

DiffMerge comes with a command-line script that opens the GUI from the terminal, which is handy.

Comment: I had missed this one, and tried it now. Looks really really nice, I'm going to accept this answer, because I think that even KDiff is very nice, this might be the closest to the Meld niceness.

Comment: `opendiff` is nice too.